# Why does minMaxLoc return nonsense and the image is all black?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I've got a bit of a head scratcher, because this is something I must have done a thousand times in OpenCV 2.4, but doesn't work in OpenCV 3.

The problem is the following:

```
cv::Mat disparity = cv::Mat::zeros(input_left.rows, input_left.cols, CV_32FC1); // I initialize the matrix like this
//Loop:
    disparity.at<float>(y, x, 1) = float value; // I fill it up in a loop
```

Which seems to work allright, since when I print out the values in a loop using:

```
std::cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << " - " << disparity.at<float>(y, x, 1);
```

I get values I was expecting. Now, I need to convert the float values to an uchar mat, which I have always done by calling `normalize` to get the values between 0-255 and then `convertTo` to change the representation. For some reason this failed miserably (Result was all zeros), so I attempted doing:

```
double d_minVal = 0.;
double d_maxVal = 0.;
cv::minMaxLoc(disparity, &d_minVal, &d_maxVal);
```

to scale the pixels myself. I know the values are in there, because when I print out disparities pixel by pixel I get values somewhere between 0 and 400, as expected, but minMaxLoc returns:

```
d_minVal = d_maxVal = 2.42214e-41
```

which is just completely wrong.

There's no error, nothing to go on. It's just a weird behaving matrix. Most OpenCV functions act as if it was filled with near zero values. Was there any change in OpenCV 3.x behavior which I am not aware of? I'd switch back to 2.4, but I've already spent hours rewriting another 10 apps in the set to work on 3.0. Or am I just missing something obvious?

I am going to try and debug it myself now, but lldb is a pain.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: `disparity.at<float>(y, x, 1)` - this would be the **2nd** channel, not the 1st, you're simply out of bounds !!

Comment: Oh, I am an absolute moron! :D Thank you very much, sleep deprivation is really something. Strange that OpenCV doesn't complain when I do that to a single channel Matrix, I'd expect at() would do some boundary checking. Could you please post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Thinking about it, how the hell are the values saved when the channel doesn't exist. Does OpenCV simply interpret the single channel matrix data array as a multichannel for at()? Seems weird.

Comment: it will complain, once you run a debug build (that's what it is for...). and the values are just stored at position +1

Comment: I am on a debug build though. It usually complains about anything, but not this. I fixed the indexes everywhere and NOW I get a segfault. Still, thank you very much though, I can handle it from here. :)